# Is the Primefaces p:editor safe to use?

Tags: javascript, security, primefaces, xss

I mean, the primefaces p:editor uses html to structure the text, so I have to set the escape attribute of h:outputText to false, to show the output without html tags.

I was trying to play around a bit with this component, and entered the following a javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div").text("haha");
    })
</script>
```

The output was the same (I got a simple text, no js execution) till I turned on the option 'Show Source' and entered the same. Now when I was trying to display the text, te javascript was executed and ruined the page.

So my question would be:
Is there a vulnerability in my approach, implementation, usage of this component; or the p:editor is so vulnerable? Should I use a simple textarea instead, or is there a way to turn remove this option from the editor?

Comment: This is not different from opening the browser console (or even putting `javascript:...` in the url) and running JS in the context of the current page. So, no the pure feasibility of this, is no security risk in itself.

Comment: I see, but what if I save the text in DB and let it display to other users (comment on a blog for example)? Maybe I'm wrong, but the script will be executed for them? Should I always check the text upon saving and remove the unwanted <script>, <frame>, <iframe>, etc. tags? (Sry if it is a noobish question)

Comment: Yes that's correct. So in the end it's very simple. Don't trust user provided data (e.g. either strip malicious text while saving or escape it while displaying, there are tons of good articles about the topic ;)).

Answer (score -2):

you can disable any control of the editor by the attribute "controls"

http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/primefaces/users-guide/p-editor.pdf

bold
•
italic
•
underline
•
strikethrough
•
subscript
•
superscript
•
font
•
size
•
style
•
color
•
highlight
•
bullets
•
numbering
•
alignleft
•
center
•
alignright
•
justify
•
undo
•
redo
•
rule
•
image
•
link
•
unlink
•
cut
•
copy
•
paste
•
pastetext
•
print
•
source
•
outdent
•
indent
•
removeFormat

You can use any of the above keywords to specity which controls you want

eg :

Comment: Do you claim that disabling the controls is sufficient to make the editor "safe"? If so, what prevents an attacker from reenabling these buttons using JavaScript?